# Wordpress Widget Freeze in dashboard

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have one problem that my widget menu doesn't showed up in apperance menu, I solved by adding the following code to my functions.php at the end of the file:

```
    function arphabet_widgets_init() {

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => 'Home right sidebar',
        'id' => 'home_right_1',
        'before_widget' => '<div>',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h2 class="rounded">',
        'after_title' => '</h2>',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'arphabet_widgets_init' );
```

The widget appear in the menu Appearance->widget , and widget page open in the dashboard, the problem is everything in this page is freezes I can't click or drag any item as if none of `JavaScript` files are loaded, my Wordpress Version is 4.8.2,any help please:
[Dashboard Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gBzP.png)

Answer (score 1):

Disable recently installed plugins and check it again. It will fix your issues.

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution and worked fine for me which is, adding the following code to wp-config.php file:

```
define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);
```

now the dashboard is working fine, i don't know if the above code will affect any other functionality in word press but it work for the widget hopefully somebody benefit from this.

[Solution Reference](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20835/javascript-not-working-in-admin)